# Auto reload with supervisor in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, node-supervisor

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "lays-vroubek",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "supervisor ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "less-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "reload": "^0.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "supervisor": "^0.9.1"
  }
}
```

My app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(lessMiddleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
      force: true,
      debug: true,
      once: false
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

I run my app with comand: `"$ DEBUG=lays-vroubek:* npm start"` but auto-reload does not work without any error msg (app runs)

> lays-vroubek@0.0.0 start /Users/jan.michalik/Workspace/Sites/lays-vroubek
>   supervisor ./bin/www

Running node-supervisor with
  program './bin/www'
  --watch '.'
  --extensions 'node,js,/bin/www'
  --exec 'node'

Starting child process with 'node ./bin/www'
Watching directory '/Users/jan.michalik/Workspace/Sites/lays-vroubek' for changes.
Press rs for restarting the process.
  lays-vroubek:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you have an express app named `backend`. Than you can use

`DEBUG=backend:* supervisor -w server -e ejs,js,json bin/www`

to autorestart express app if any of ejs, js or json files is changed inside `server` dir (usual, i place my express app into `server` dir)